# get a specific variable's field value to display in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of declared string variables that are name codes who's field values are full names. Can I get a specific variable's field value to display in a textbox if I know what the variable name is?

Example variables

```
Dim GLAN01 As String = "Langer Georg"
Dim BEDW01 As String = "Edwards Brian"
Dim MRIG01 As String = "Riggins Michael"
```

Comment: That depends on when you know variable name. If it is at compile time, means you know it at the time you write the code, the answer is as simple as demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question correctly. How about this pattern? :

```
textBoxName.Text = variableNameToDisplay
```

for example :

```
textBox1.Text = GLAN01
```

to display `Langer Georg` text in `textBox1`

**UPDATE :**

If I understand what you are after correctly, one possible way is using dictionary to store mapping of code name to full name (instead of using multiple variables). With dictionary you can get full name string given any code name string easily, for example :

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From _
                {{"GLAN01", "Langer Georg"},
                {"BEDW01", "Edwards Brian"},
                {"MRIG01", "Riggins Michael"}}
textBox1.Text = dict("GLAN01")
```

For reference, in case you are not familiar yet with collection initializer syntax as in above example :

[MSDN : Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx) (particularly "Nesting Collection Initializer" section)

Comment: I would recommend a constant as this seems it wouldn't change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. More specifically, I would not know the variable name at compile time. I need a way to compare the value I get to my declared string variables when I query the dataset.

Comment: check my updated answer, and see if that suits your requirement.